# Не могу добавить add_child в таблицу

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-model

При добавлении `add_child` в таблицу `Page`

```
obj_cruise = self.obj_cruise_index.add_child(
                    instance=Cruise(**options))
```

получаю ошибку:

```
ОШИБКА:  значение NULL в столбце "translation_key" отношения "wagtailcore_page" нарушает ограничение NOT NULL
```

Но ведь translation_key должен сам генерироваться, разве нет?
В чём здесь проблема, подскажите?
Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: добавьте в вопрос всю модель Page?